# New folder created in vscode not committing?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I cloned my git repository to vscode. It was blank at the time.

I created multiple files and I committed them with the terminal code `git push origin main`. No problem there.

But I later put the JS file, the HTML file and the CSS file into folders.

Now, when I check `git status`, as normal it shows me the items to commit. But when I run the commit command it says "everything is up to date"... when it obviously isnt.

Any idea?

See image:

[Image of my vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1abf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit your files before you can push them.

**Use:**

```sh
git commit -m "your commit message here"
```

**Then you can use:**

```sh
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

**No Commit**
You forgot to commit your changes. So even if you try to push, you haven't got anything to push, that's why it says everything is up to date.

Comment: This answer is correct, but could have been made even better had you also included details on how to do it